Convert linear output of current mirror to exponential
I am currently trying to change the output from my current mirror, which is linear, to a more exponential one.
The picture below shows the current mirror I'm using, which is intended to work from 8 to 28 V.

What I would like is for the current to act like the graph below:

What changes could I do to the current mirror?
Thank you for your help!
EDIT:
Okay so I changed Q2 with a resistor and seems to be near the good result. Is there any way for the current not to be this linear in the end and to go "higher" (green is still the current)?


what do you consider the "input" and what the "output" of your circuit, precisely? Is the input the voltage at Q2's collector? The current through R1? The voltage between R3 and R2?

and: if you want exponential behaviour, why the current mirror? A single transistor has a very exponential base voltage to collector-emitter current curve (assuming fixed V_CE). You specifically build two-transistor circuits to get rid of that exponential behaviour.

@MarcusMüller the output current is the current going from V2 to the emettor of Q1 (Ic in green). Right now it's proportional to the input voltage (blue)

OK; so then, why the current mirror?

@MarcusMüller it was earlier design, I needed to have the linear current ouput, but now that i need it to be exponential, I was wondering if I could just slightly change the current mirror to avoid changing the schematics too much...

You can slightly change the design by not having a current mirror, as said. I mean, we're talking about two components.

I ended up removing Q2 and replaced it with a resistor, result is in the edit. The end is still very much linear

have you seen tobalt's edit to his answer? You might need to refresh your basics of transistors, to be honest. Have you tried changing the base resistor?

I'm still a student in electronics engineering so I still have much to learn :) That's what I am currently trying to do

Excellent! So, really, revisit your basics of transistors. The exponential curve is literally what we've been thought in the first lecture about them. Long, long before we were thought any circuits like current mirrors.

If you wish to have a linear-input to exponential-output current conversion, simply replace Q2 with a resistor.
The whole point of the diode-transistor current mirror is to turn the naturally exponential behavior of the output transistor into a linear one.
If you want to have an exponential behavior over a very wide input voltage range, you should remove Q2 entirely (no resistor either), and then change R1 according to your liking.

Hello, thanks for your answer ! I tried to simulate such a circuit but can't seem to have anything, could you show me the schematics you had in mind ? Thanks !

@Nucrino try with a 10 kOhm resistor instead of Q2 and go from there.

okay so I tried and it seems to be working for the beginning of the curve, meaning we do have this "elbow", but after that we are very much linear, I'm going to try to edit my post to show the results

@Nucrino see my edit please

Thank you for your help, currently my problem is that I have troubles to obtain the same current I had as the ouput of the current mirror (much higher with a single transistor)

@Nucrino so, adjust your resistors.

@Nucrino If the output current is too large, then increase R1 (by several orders of magnitude if necessary). A resistor in the former place of Q2 will also help to reduce output current, but it will also reduce the range of the exponential behavior

@tobalt I'm gonna try to find a suitable middle ground, thanks for your help

The basic idea is that there are two thermally-coupled transistors Q1 and Q2. There is a reference current flowing through Q1. Q1's Vbe is then buffered by the buffer VCVS1. Then, the control voltage V1 is added to Q1's Vbe, and is used to drive Q2's base. The relationship between V1 and Ic(Q2) is exponential:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Now we can work towards turning it into a more practical circuit. First, we can convert V1 to a current and drop it across a resistor - here, R1 - to make V1 ground-referenced instead of an "in-line" source:

simulate this circuit
R3 sets the voltage-to-current scaling:

Instead of using an ideal buffer for Q1's V(be), we can use an op-amp. The 0.1mA current source takes two transistors.

simulate this circuit
The voltage follower can be made from discrete transistors instead:

simulate this circuit
Q1 is the Vbe reference for Q2. They should be a dual transistor in one package, so that they'd be well thermally connected. Or, Q1 and Q2 should be in TO-126 package, and screwed together back-to-back, with some thermal compound between them.
Q3 is the current source Vbe reference. Q4 is the 0.1mA current source that biases Q1.
Q5..Q11 form a voltage follower.
Q5 is the current 0.01mA current source that biases the differential pair Q6 and Q7. Q8 and Q9 is the current mirror load for the differential pair. Q6 and Q7 should be in the same dual package, and so should be Q8 and Q9.
Q10 is the voltage amplifier, and Q11+R8 are the output stage that drive the base of Q2.
